# .NET,C# ,IIS 7.5 - How to rewrite url

Tags: iis-7.5

I need to rewrite the URL:

http://www.mydomain.com/test.aspx?pagename=quotes&companycode=324543

To

http://www.mydomain.com/test/quotes/324543

I am Using IIS 7.5 and VS 2008.

I need the text to insert in web.config.

Answer (score 2):

Install [URL Rewriting](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) then inside web.config at the XML path system.webServer/rewrite/rules

```
<rule name="Rule" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="test.aspx" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="pagename=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)&amp;companycode=([0-9]+)" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="test/{C:1}/{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

If you don't need all parameters in the query string then you can replace the regex and parameters ({C:1}/{C:2}) with their literals.